# Optional itemin a swagger yaml definition

Tags: yaml, swagger

I have the following deinition in swagger.yaml

```
Content:
    type: object
    properties:
        text:
          type: string
        image:
            ref: "#/definitions/Image"
            allowEmptyValue: true
```

I get Additional properties not allowed: allowEmptyValue as an error

How do I make image optional? ie might only be text no images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allowEmptyValue` applies only to query parameters and means a different thing -
 the parameter is included, but its value may be empty, as in `?param=`.

In schemas, **all properties are optional by default**. You can make certain properties required by including them in the `required` array. Properties not listed in `required` are considered optional.

```yaml
Content:
    type: object
    properties:
        text:
          type: string
        image:
            ref: "#/definitions/Image"
    # text is required, image is optional
    required:
        - text
```